# (Pymongo) Print/show what I just delete

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

**I want to print what I just deleted by pymongo**

- the main function

```
def del_data(del_values_json ,one_or_many_bool ):
  if one_or_many_bool:
        x = mycol.delete_many(del_values_json)

  else:
        x = mycol.delete_one(del_values_json)
  retrun x


number_of_delete_data = int(x.deleted_count)


modified_data_list = []
for modified_data in mycol.find().sort("_id", -1).limit(number_of_delete_data):
        print(modified_data)
        modified_data_list.append(modified_data)
```

- the output

I want to print what I just deleted, I delete two `{ "name": "Joy22" }`data, but I just print the top of 2 data in the collection, MongoDB has some examples, however, is hard to find pymongo call for the same case

```
Enter the IP: localhost.173
Enter exist DB name: (practice_10_14)-0002
Enter exist collection name: collection_new02cp
U are deleted one or many values? (ex:1 for many , 0 for one): 1
Enter delete values: { "name" : "Joy22" }
<pymongo.results.DeleteResult object at 0x00000282A37C6890>
2 documents delete.
{'_id': ObjectId('6350c8a3a1fa85dd0cfe590a'), 'name': 'Joy', 'ID': 100998, 'Age': 23, 'time': DateTime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 9, 11, 54)}
{'_id': ObjectId('6350c8a3a1fa85dd0cfe5909'), 'name': 'Joy', 'ID': 100998, 'Age': 23, 'time': DateTime.datetime(2022, 10, 17, 9, 11, 54)}
{'ok': 1, 'msg': 'no error occur', 'count': 2}
<class 'str'>
```

- the whole code in case someone wants to take a look

```
# Delete collection/table 
import pymongo
import datetime
import json
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson import json_util

def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    try:
            myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
            mydb = myclient[db]
            mycol = mydb[coll]
    except Exception as e:
            msg_fail_reason = "error in init_db function"
            return msg_fail_reason

    return mydb, mycol

# del_data = delete_db_data
# one_or_many_bool: input 1 means True; input 0 is False

def del_data(del_values_json ,one_or_many_bool ):
    try:
            if one_or_many_bool:
                    x = mycol.delete_many(del_values_json)

            else:
                    x = mycol.delete_one(del_values_json)

    except Exception as e:
            msg_fail_reason = "error in del_data function"
            return msg_fail_reason   
    return x


msg_fail_reason = "no error occur"

ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)


insert_one_or_many = input("U are delete one or many values? (ex:1 for many , 0 for one): ")
del_values_str = input("Enter delete values: ")

one_or_many_bool = bool(int(insert_one_or_many))

del_values_json =json.loads(del_values_str)
x = del_data(del_values_json ,one_or_many_bool )

print(x)
print(x.deleted_count, "documents delete.")

number_of_delete_data = int(x.deleted_count)



modified_data_list = []
for modified_data in mycol.find().sort("_id", -1).limit(number_of_delete_data):
        print(modified_data)
        modified_data_list.append(modified_data)


def parse_json(data):
    return json.loads(json_util.dumps(data))

# if someone wants data in JSON 
    # modified_data_json = parse_json(modified_data_list)


# 1 means success 
return_status_str = { "ok" : 1 , "msg" : msg_fail_reason , "count" : number_of_delete_data}
print(return_status_str)

# return_status_json is json data, dump 
return_status_json = (json.dumps(return_status_str))

print(type(return_status_json))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DeleteResult` object only returns the number of items deleted. Once an item is deleted it will no longer occur in the collection so this fragment of code:

```
modified_data_list = []
for modified_data in mycol.find().sort("_id", -1).limit(number_of_delete_data):
        print(modified_data)
        modified_data_list.append(modified_data)
```

Will return the first two remaining items which implies there were two documents with the name `joy22` (hence a modified count of 2). You will note that the two documents returned do not have the name `joy22`. Therefore they are not the deleted documents.

To achieve your goal first `find` your documents, then `delete_many` then print the results of the `find`.

Comment: hi @Joe Drumgoole, so the only solution is to print the rest ?  I get ur idea that " `DeleteResult object only returns the number of items deleted` ", is there any way to show what I delete, maybe in other object name or in mongoDB record etc......

Comment: Once they are deleted they are gone. You could set up a change stream and it would report the documents that were deleted as they were deleted https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/